# Git: Getting commits with a ticket number

Tags: regex, git

Okay, so I'm trying to find out if a ticket has been included in my release branch. The tickets are all built out of a project id and an id number, e.g. (PRO-123). I've tried this command:

```
git log --date=short --format="%h: %ad (%cn)  %s" --abbrev-commit --grep='[A-Z]+-[0-9]+'
```

But it's not returning anything. If I take away the `--grep` part there's loads of matches to the pattern. For instance:

```
a6fdcd0: 2016-03-16 (ajfaraday)  Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop_5.2_customer' into release_5.2_customer
85d107a: 2016-03-16 (username)  Merge pull request #477 from myapp/fix_CST-827_outline_method_in_use_check
6024bda: 2016-03-16 (Andrew Faraday)  Merge pull request #473 from myapp/fix_CST-810_soap_container_create_bounds
eec2a61: 2016-03-16 (ajfaraday)  added missing stubs
c03b3cb: 2016-03-15 (username)  Merge pull request #472 from myapp/fix_CST-490_options_are_clickable_for_user_without_module_admin_rights
728539b: 2016-03-15 (username)  Merge pull request #474 from myapp/fix_CST-873_hidden_error_on_pev_validation
4a11dd7: 2016-03-15 (username)  Merge pull request #475 from myapp/fix_CST-854_copy_process_version_project_element_values
4a5af44: 2016-03-15 (ajfaraday)  CST-854: fixed in-use check for methods
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those matched patterns correct or wrong ?

Comment: @noob I'm not sure I understand the question. The result of my command is nothing, just the next command line prompt. But if I look at the commits, lots of commit messages contain the pattern.

Comment: You said _If I take away the --grep part there's loads of matches to the pattern._ So are these matches correct or wrong ?

Comment: Can you post strings without the `grep` so we can look if the pattern is able to match? At the moment, only sth. like [`AAAAAA-1234567890`](https://regex101.com/r/yU4qO3/1) would be able to match at all.

Comment: If I remove the `--grep` part then it's just a formatted git log, unfiltered. I'll add some examples, but it'll have to be careful, because it's in a closed repo.

Comment: Added some example output without the `--grep` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've found the problem. It's some minor language difference in regexes (I'm usually writing them in my Ruby code).

For some reason `[A-Z]+` wasn't matching but `[A-Z]*` is working fine. This line does what I wanted:

```
git log --date=short --format="%h: %ad (%cn)  %s" --abbrev-commit --grep="[A-Z]*-[0-9]*"
```

Comment: Try it with the `+` again but add an `-E` (or `--extended-regexp`) as well.